# ELK stack error elastic search don't authorize Logstash

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, elk

I followed up [this blog](https://cassiomolin.com/2019/06/30/log-aggregation-with-spring-boot-elastic-stack-and-docker/)  to start ELK stack from docker compose file but used version 8.1.2. It is not running successfully elastic search don't authorize Logstash.

The error from Logstash is `[main] Attempted to resurrect connection to dead ES instance, but got an error {:url=>"http://elasticsearch:9200/", :exception=>LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch::HttpClient::Pool::BadResponseCodeError, :message=>"Got response code '401' contacting Elasticsearch at URL 'http://elasticsearch:9200/'"}`

Answer (score 0):

did you try to use HTTPS instead of HTTP as the security in ES 8 version is enabled by default.